# Invalid character in header content ["authorization"] when sending bearer authorization request from thunder client

Tags: node.js, express, vscode-extensions

**server.js**

i tried to send an bearer token through thunder-client visual-studio code extension but got an error
**Invalid character in header content ["authorization"]**

*but it working fine with postman*

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("welcome to the main page")
})
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    

     const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']
   
    if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined'){
        
        console.log(req.headers)
        console.log(bearerHeader)
        res.send(req)
    }else{
        res.status(403)
   }
    
    //bearer.header.split('')
})


app.listen(8000,()=>console.log("server is running"))
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple express app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "source.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

[the error is shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Afil.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR5az.png)

can anyone help me on this thanks in advance

Comment: I had almost the same problem, although I used the "Auth" / "Bearer" Tab to enter the value. The problem was that somehow the client seemingly added line breaks. Completely removing all characters (until I see the placeholder text), and then re-inserting my token *without linebreaks* solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the typo in the extension.

Please replace **Content-type** with **content-type**.

This issue occurs because the "C" is capital in the headers.

Comment: still got the same problem

Comment: its look like thunder-client not forward the request to the server.js

Comment: I personally used postman the most. So, recommended to stick with it :D

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a new line in the Authorization field by going down with the arrow key.

Solution: Delete the whole content until `enter token` palceholder is not visible and type it agin.

Answer (score 0):

I saw it on a completely unrelated (mostly) Github thread from another tool. If you copied the token from the browser, instead of `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V`-ing it, just right click and select `Copy value`, and it should work. This is because somewhere in the text you copied there is an ellipsis (three dots), most likely.

This is the thread: https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/942#issuecomment-1054272212

And this is how you need to do it (it's in Spanish, but it says `Copy value` on the first line and `Copy all` on the second):

[image]